# Where are my apps?

Tags: unity

When I click on the dash icon in Ubuntu 12.10, it shows me some "Applications", but only eight of them.

Where are the other apps? How can I browse for "System", "Programming", "Multimedia" and other sections to find and install tons of apps?

I don't want to type to the search bar, I want to locate all the apps with a couple of clicks like in Metacity and Gnome 2.

Comment: I've deleted your second question, since there should only be one question per post on AskUbuntu. Please go ahead and post the second question in another post. You can access the edit history of this question by clicking on the date next to "edited".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you press on the '' start icon'' (it is called Dash) the first window you see is your home window you can search files/apps in it and so on. you can see some icons on the bottom of the window  home, tools, camera etc (this icons are called lenses)
[image]
 press on the tools box and then press on the filter results there you can see your apps categorized 
If you do not like the spam you are getting in the dash menu
tip this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

after the restart they will not appear any more

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I'll try this stuff before throwing away Ubuntu for Mint Cinnamon.

Comment: glad I could help
this is my opinion only and I'm a windows user for me gnu/linux is a bit strange but I love things I can do with it.
 first I love the community really if you have a question they will answer it.
 second is the performance I get with linux any way back to the topic for me linux mint is a bit easier  to use for really new users after that I think linux mint is not that good I hate it's washed out look and the community reacts really slow to your questions and in general I do not like it's look. I think yes ubuntu is a bit harder to start with but in the end it works better

Comment: Lol!!! I feel ashamed! I'm a Linux user since 14 years ago. The last Windows I touched was Windows Me (98 with a subtle disguise) and been using Debian based distros for many several years. Is just that to be honest, I HATE ubuntu since 11.04 (millions of people feel the same) and I was using 10.10 until now that my new Laptop's Graphics card is not recognized by the old kernel and is unable to run compiz.

I really recomend to you Linux Mint Maya 14, is lovely (but sadly no compiz still)

Comment: everything makes seance now 
you are a old linux user and you do not like ubuntu 11.-12.10 :) as most old user
 I am a new gnu/linux user and I like ubuntu :) ah make seance about mint I do not know why but I can not use it, it's washed out look hearts my eyes after some time I do not know why and the same goes for other ubuntu flavors except gnome 3