# I was looking for the command line and have no clue where it is

Tags: 12.04

I haven't used linux in a long while. This version of Ubuntu is very different from the one i've used in the past. I was looking for the command line and have no clue where it is.

Also, where are all the apps located at? I downloaded and installed Chromium, but I don't know how to open it.

Comment: chromium: hit {windows key} and type c h r o m i u m. At some point it will show up ;) BUT it SHOULD be in the launcher after install :)

Comment: *Where are your apps?* **See**: http://askubuntu.com/q/223582/62483

Answer (score 0):

To open the command line Terminal just press <kbd>ctr</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

please give us a little more information. What version of ubuntu did you downlaod?

on the left side you have a sidebar, there is the terminal as well.

Comment: The tag says 12.04